# How to load a form/page into a div via AJAX?

Tags: 8, ajax

I want to open the create user form (`/admin/people/create`) into a specific `div` via AJAX. I can currently open such forms into a modal window using the following link format:

```html
<a href="/admin/people/create" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal">
    Add user
</a>
```

Is there any way to load this form/page into a `div` instead of into a modal window?

Comment: If you down vote and mark a question to be closed, then be courageous enough to leave a comment about why and what is not clear about the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core does not provide an HTML format for non-dialogs, but you can create your own custom format.

mymodule/js/**custom-ajax-loader.js**:

```js
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myCustomAJAXStuff = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $("a.use-custom-ajax", context).once('mymodule-ajax').each(function(i, ajaxLink) {
        const $linkElement = $(ajaxLink);

        const elementSettings = {
          url: $linkElement.attr("href"),
          event: 'click',
          progress: {type: 'throbber'},
          element: ajaxLink,
        };

        const myAjaxObject = Drupal.ajax(elementSettings);

        // Declare a new Ajax command specifically for this Ajax object.
        myAjaxObject.commands.insert = function (ajax, response) {
          let target = $linkElement.attr("target");
          $(target).html(response.data);
        };
      });
    },
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

mymodule.libraries.yml:

```yaml
mymodule.ajax:
  js:
    js/custom-ajax-loader.js: { }
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal.ajax
```

Add the library wherever needed: [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module#attaching)

Then when you create your link

```
<a href="/admin/people/create" class="use-custom-ajax" target="#some-div-id">
    Add user
</a>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a million for your help. Can I edit your post to put my complete code, including defining the library etc?

Comment: Go for it, do whatever changes you want. I was lazy to add the libraries stuff.

Comment: Thanks, done! :)

Comment: I have a problem with the ajax loaded form. Maybe I should create another question, but I wanted to have your idea first.  If I click on any "add another item" buttons on the form, the page is reloaded and redirects to `/admin/people/create`, breaking the whole ajax experience. Do you have any suggestion about this?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. You need to add `url` and `options` keys to `#ajax` of the "add another item" button. See for example [Ajax submission not working for Webform within a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/297405/27710) and for your route use `user.admin_create`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll try that.